# How can I concat or merge 4 different dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Whenever I try to concat([]) more than 3 dataframes I get disorganized results or output.

I.E: When i concat three or two dataframes I get complete data,but when I attempt to concat a 4th dataframe. It doesn't gives me all the columns and gives the results a lil disorganized.

results = pd.concat([d1, d2, d3], axis= 1, join = 'inner')

'Code above gives me complete data'

results = pd.concat([d1, d2, d3, d4], axis= 1, join = 'inner')

'Code above gives me incomplete data columns'

Help please!

Thanks

Comment: Without additional info on the structure of the dataframes in question (preferrably samples that allow us to reproduce the issue), we won't be able to properly help you. One possible explanation would be that `d4` is lacking some columns that the other three have and `join='inner'` results in them getting dropped, but that's just an educated guess without actually seeing the dfs

Answer (score 0):

`pd.concat` should work for this. Can you please show the output

meanwhile try using the following:

```
merged_df = (df1.merge(df2).merge(df3).merge(df4))
```